# Nav Sub Menu Links list full width of container, NOT the width of the menu item they are nested in

Tags: html, css, nav, submenu

I am creating Sub Menus on my current simple Nav menu bar. When I hover over the Nav link for "Treatments", the sub menu items drop down nicely and central to the above Link but the background colour spreads across the whole of the container (same width as full Nav bar). What I would like is the Sub Menu to drop down below at same width as the "Treatments" link above.
I have added snippet below for people to see where I'm going wrong.

```css
@charset"UTF-8";

nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #1C75BC;
  color: white;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
nav a:link,
nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #1C75BC;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  /* Safari */
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  /* Opera */
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #4dacff;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  font-size: 10px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul ul li {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testcss.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.leftyslaser.co.uk">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.leftyslaser.co.uk/faq.html">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.leftyslaser.co.uk/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Treatments</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Laser Tattoo Removal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Carbon Facial Skin Rejuvenation</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.leftyslaser.co.uk/about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Remove `background-color: #1C75BC;` from the nav declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1nohe6Lq/)**

Use `inline-block` instead of `block`. Using `display: block` makes the element display across the entire browser.

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found it was the background-colour on the nav declaration that was causing me the issue.

Comment: Cool, there is always multiple solutions to everything. Glad that one helped. @mbuk89

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background-color: #1C75BC;` from the nav declaration.